# AddThis Plugin adding html comments in P tags

Tags: plugins, comments, tags, html

I am using a plugin called AddThis on a website at: http://minionsphotography.com/. With AddThis enabled I am getting some extra P tags in-between the header and the text on the page: `<p><!-- AddThis Sharing Buttons above --></p>`, this adds a lot of extra space and shouldn't be there. *On the homepage it's the space between the Welcome header and the slideshow image.

Is there a function or something out there that I could use to find and remove the html comment on the page to eliminate the extra space? I use a plugin called pSquirrel to detect and remove empty P tags, but it won't remove this one (I'm guessing because pSquirrel doesn't think it's empty because of the html comment).

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: I can't see anything like you mentioned in your website. Can you please add a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to my `functions.php` file, which removes all html comments, which eliminates the issue.

I found the solution here: https://www.thewebtaylor.com/articles/wordpress-remove-html-comments

```
function callback($buffer) {
    $buffer = preg_replace('/<!--(.|s)*?-->/', '', $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}
function buffer_start() {
    ob_start("callback");
}
function buffer_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
}
add_action('get_header', 'buffer_start');
add_action('wp_footer', 'buffer_end');
```

Answer (score 0):

You put this function there:

```
$("#main").each(function() {
                var text = $(this).text();
                text = text.replace("<p><!-- AddThis Sharing Buttons above --></p>", "");
                $(this).text(text);
            });
```

Did it work?

If not, why do you want to do that? You can go to the main plugin and replace this text..

Comment: Hey there, nope, unfortunately not...I try not to modify plugins, so I figured a little jQuery would do the trick, but for some reason I was mistaken. The reason why I want to is simple, because of the amount of space between the header and the text...and honestly it shouldn't be there. Now on several other sites this is not happening with the AddThis plugin, so I'm really not sure why I'm seeing it here.